# Error on \caption for figure

Tags: floats, captions

When I use \caption for figure, I got a compilation error:

```
Undefined control sequence.
<argument> {\captionfonts
               \csname fnum@\@captype \endcsname : \ignorespaces ...
\caption{Figure} \label{fig1}
```

If no `\caption`, it is correct. I don't know why?
The following is the codes:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}%

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=10pt, labelsep=endash, font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}%

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h]%
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}
\hfill
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[
natheight=2.391600in,
natwidth=2.514400in,
height=2.3916in,
width=2.5144in
]{graphics/Error.pdf}%
\caption{Figure} \label{fig1}%
\end{center}
\end{figure}


\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't get any errors. Probably you are using an out dated tex distribution!. Please try to update.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 1):

The only mention I could find of a non command `\captionfonts` is some code in a comp.text.tex thread

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.text.tex/nqkKIHsRhLA/AzNKOaYNJc0J

the `caption` package has a similar `\captionfont` (no `s` command).

Either way it appears that you have previously loaded some code that defined such a command and not are not defining it now, but some code is still using it.

Delete any `.aux` or `.toc` files and start with a clean run with latex as far as I can see it should then run without error.